# Organization or posters for "Leave No Trace" in Sweden

Tags: leave-no-trace, human-waste, sweden

Is there any organizations for "Leave No Trace" in Sweden? I'm looking for literature that outlines the "Leave No Trace" ethics in Swedish.

I've been doing some trekking in Northern Sweden. Unfortunately, I've seen:

1. soiled toilet paper and soap in streams within a few meters of the water source (spring or alpine snow)
2. almost no information at the trailhead about how to dispose of human waste

The trailheads list some basic rules, such as only burning dead & down wood and keeping dogs on leashes (a big problem for reindeer herds here), but I've only seen signage on one trail that said to dig a cathole and pack-out toilet paper (though it didn't say how far the cathole should be from water).

Are there any organizations that have produced literature about the Leave No Trace principles in the Swedish language?

Comment: Fjällräven (a Swedish outdoor clothing org) has this webpage, including a paragraph (in Swedish language) and an animated video (no words) explaining how to dispose of human waste in the backcountry https://classic.fjallraven.com/sweden/sv/2018/10/12/under-vandringen/

Comment: Please produce some in Russian as well and send them to Yugyd Va National Park…

Comment: @gerrit I was thinking of making one myself. Are you a native Russian speaker that can help with the translation?

Comment: @HoboHacker No, not at all.  But I was appalled by the toilet paper mess at the "base camp" of the Manaraga, which is close to the most remote place I've ever been.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps it's a cultural thing, but I couldn't find anything in Swedish that spelled it out quantitatively (60m from streams, 20cm holes), so I created one myself.

#### My "Leave No Trace" Poster

[image: Leave No Trace (English, Swedish, German)]

A printable pdf and source svg can be found here:

- https://hobohacker.net/lnt

### Swedish Sources

Though I couldn't find any organizations with a web presence in Sweden that provides quantitative explanations about how to properly dispose of waste in the backcountry, I did see many related organizations with some information about how to responsibly travel in the backcountry:

[Håll Sverige Rent (Keep Sweden Clean)](https://hsr.se/allemansr%C3%A4tten)

[Naturvårdsverket (Swedish Environmental Protection Agency)](https://www.naturvardsverket.se/amnesomraden/allemansratten/)

[Sveriges Nationalparker (Swedish National Parks)](https://www.nationalparksofsweden.se/national-park-facts/security-and-regulations/)

[Fjällräven Pooping Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJ0MI7p-VZQ)

Comment: See also https://old.reddit.com/r/Svenska/comments/wedpxc/translating_leave_no_trace_frontcountry_trekking/

Comment: It would IMHO be better to translate also the title to German. It would then be `Befolge die "Lasse nichts zurück"-Regeln`. Dann wäre es besser, zu schreiben `Nimm eine Karte und einen Kompass mit. Lerne...` Und es ist einfacher zu lesen, wenn du ä, ö und ü brauchst (z.B. `Müll` statt `Muell`).

Comment: I don't understand the point with the fire. Why shouldn't fires be started high up?

Comment: @PMF alpine areas are fragile ecosystems with very little wood that takes a long time to grow. Fires are often banned at such high altitudes to protect them.

Comment: @PMF I've updated the German text in the graphics, thanks!